# MSYS2 gcc locks up the Windows PC

Tags: gcc, msys2

I have installed MSYS2 on Windows 11.

I'm using cmake and gcc to compile a small C project, with something like 50 C source files, for a command-line application.

The compilations have been halting something like 80% through the build, and then causing the whole computer to lock up and become unresponsive over the course of a few seconds. The only remedy has been to reboot and try again.

I've tried both the 32-bit and 64-bit tools. Eg pacman package `mingw-w64-i686-gcc` and `mingw-w64-i686-cmake`, or `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc` and `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-cmake`.

This is on a Dell laptop that's probably 1 or 2 years old, with 32 GB RAM, running Windows 11 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I found two things which avoid the lock-up of the PC. Either solution works by itself.

1. Do a build with the cmake option `--parallel 1` (aka `-j 1`).
2. Arrange to have the MSYS2 tools excluded from the Trend Micro Security virus scanner.
   I installed them in a directory that is marked as excluded from scanning.

When excluded from Trend, the whole compilation runs much faster. It seems that Trend is really the root-cause of this issue.